# Taming NSTextField with bindings and formatter to behave properly

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to have a window that needs to accept some user input, for this I have the following:

- `NSWindow` loaded from nib with `NSWindowController`, which is also its delegate
- Couple of `NSTextField`'s with `NSNumberFormatter`
- Using bindings, the `NSTextField`'s are bound to a integer properties in the `NSWindowController` (I didn't used `NSObjectController` for simplicity but can add it if needed)
- A 'done' `NSButton` which the user clicks when finished to accept the changes and close the window
- In controller's `windowShouldClose:` method do a final validation and decide whether I can close the window

What I want to achieve is pretty simple, yet Cocoa insists on making this challenging:

- `NSTextField` should accept only a number for it final value, which is also greater than zero
- If the user tries to insert non numeric values or zero, there should be an alert prompting the user to fix his entry
- When the user clicks on done:

  - Do other custom validation (e.g. compare if one number is great than the other)
  - If the values are correct, accept the changes and close the window (the 'model' should be already updated with the values via bindings)
  - If the values are incorrect, the user should be prompted with a choice whether to fix the entry (leaving the window open) or close the window and discard changes

Simple enough. The NSNumberFormatter should already cover most of the task and together with the bindings, this should be pretty easy to achieve.

**Problem #1:**

I couldn't find a way to change the error message that is displayed to the user in the alert when `NSTextField` loses focus and the value is incorrect to something more descriptive. Is there any way to do this? Or I need to implement my own NSFormatter somehow?

**Problem #2:**

When user changes a value in the `NSTextField` and clicks on the 'done' button, Cocoa doesn't consider this as a trigger to update the value of the model `NSTextField` is bound to. This may be the standard OSX behavior but is something that doesn't make any sense.

I was able to work around this by calling `[window makeFirstResponder:nil]` in the action of the 'done' button to force the `NSTextField` lose focus and update the value but I wonder if this is the right way to achieve this.

**Problem #3:**

And here is where I really scratch my head. If the user enters an incorrect value (like non integers) in the `NSTextField` and click 'done' button, the validation doesn't kick in and the `NSTextField` will continue to have the incorrect values while the model is not updated.

I'd expect that the "invalid" alert will still be displayed and I have some place to insert code to make a decision whether to close the window or not but I couldn't find any way to override this behavior.

What should be the standard practices to achieve these requirements? Should I abandon the formatter and/or bindings and just do it all manually using actions?

Comment: Try "Continuously Updates Value"  and "Validates immediately" in the Bindings inspector under Value. As for the button. I just tried  `[[self window] endEditingFor:nil]`; (Found with google) which worked to the extent of ending editing. But and code after it is run. It does not wait for a response. So you would have to add something to stop that if the Alert sheet is down...I think in the past I just manually got the values and did my own  validation and alerts.

Comment: "Continuously Updates Value" is not what I want. It forces an update on every change in the NSTextField and will force update when user only entered part of the value, invoking validation prematurely, missing the user's intent. "Validates immediately" doesn't seem to be working as advertised, it effects whether the validate<Key>:error: method is called or not on the model object and has no effect on the formatter.

Comment: In my basic setup; the textfields are bound to shared users defaults 'It's value'  is using "Continuously Updates Value" which does not set off the validation and the alert. The validation is only done when editing is ended.(Thinking about it it is a good thing then the Validates Immediately does not work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For problem 1, try setting a delegate for the text fields and implementing `-control:didFailToFormatString:errorDescription:` and possibly `-control:didFailToValidatePartialString:errorDescription:`. Present any UI you want, making use of the error description or not.

Alternatively, you can implement a custom subclass of `NSNumberFormatter` and override `-getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:` and `-isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:`. You can call through to super for most of the implementation. If it fails, you can replace the error description that super supplied with a different one. You would use this approach if you need the context of the formatter object (its properties, etc.) to figure out a better error description.

The correct solution to problem 2 is to not programmatically change the first responder. Rather, you should indeed use an `NSObjectController` to mediate between the text fields and the window controller. In the action method for the Done button, call either `-commitEditing` or `-commitEditingWithDelegate:didCommitSelector:contextInfo:`. `NSObjectController` inherits those methods from `NSController`, which adopts the `NSEditor` protocol. When you get the result (synchronously for the former, asynchronously for the latter), you either proceed or do nothing depending on whether the commit succeeded or failed.

I suspect that problem 3 is also a result of programmatically changing the window's first responder. It is often the case that programmatic changes are not subject to the same checks as the corresponding change made due to user action. The frameworks assume you, the programmer know what you're doing, and so it would be "wrong" to subject a programmatic change of focus to validation by the formatter, for example.